# ¿Cómo hacer que un for no repita la misma sentencia en Java?

Tags: java, archivo, bucle-for

Estoy un poco liado ahora mismo, así que perdón si no soy claro formulando la cuestión...Resulta que tengo que hacer un ejercicio en Java el cuál copie los ficheros y carpetas que les digo **(su nombre están en un array)** a una carpeta y claro, yo utilizo un método que recibe como parámetro el directorio principal que lo que hace es listar los ficheros del directorio principal, y si es un directorio, compara su nombre con el nombre de cada uno de esos ficheros; si coincide pues lo imprimo para ver si está bien, si no coincide, vuelvo a llamar al propio método **(recursividad)** con el parámetro de ese directorio para que vuelva a comenzar y así sucesivamente. Si es un fichero, exactamente lo mismo pero ya no vuelve a llamar al método dado que es un fichero y no se puede recorrer. El caso es que, obviamente, se repiten las líneas que imprimen el nombre de los ficheros que encuentra, y claro, lo que quiero es que salga una sola vez. He probado con **break**, continue y ya haciendo cosas al azar porque ando bastante perdido.

> ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

O bien mejorando mi código o cambiándolo por completo porque no se si lo estoy haciendo bien, sinceramente estoy bastante perdido. Os adjunto también la imagen del ejercicio por si queda más claro y abajo el código que tengo:

```
public static void walkin(File buscar) {

    //La variable ficheros es el array que contiene el nombre de los ficheros y carpetas que busco

    File listaDeArchivos[] = buscar.listFiles();
    if (listaDeArchivos != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listaDeArchivos.length; i++) {

            if (listaDeArchivos[i].isDirectory()) {
                for (int z = 0; z < ficheros.length; z++) {

                    if (listaDeArchivos[i].getName().equals(ficheros[z])) {
                        System.out.println(listaDeArchivos[i].getName());
                    }
                    walkin(listaDeArchivos[i]);
                }
            } else {

                for (int z = 0; z < ficheros.length; z++) {

                    if (listaDeArchivos[i].getName().equals(ficheros[z])) {
                        System.out.println(listaDeArchivos[i].getName());
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }
} // Cierre de walkin
```

[image: EJERCICIO]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Bienvenido!

Ya casi lo tenías. Tu error era que llamabas a `walkin` de forma recursiva **independientemente de si estaba en `ficheros` o no.** Eso implica que estabas recorriendo archivos dentro de carpetas que no tenías que copiar.

Así que la llamada recursiva quedaría así:

```
if (listaDeArchivos[i].getName().equals(ficheros[z])) {
    System.out.println(listaDeArchivos[i].getName());
    walkin(listaDeArchivos[i]);
}
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias! Al final resultaba que el walkin tenía que ponerlo fuera de casi todos los for y del if, justo encima del ese, y así ya me nombraba solamente una vez cada fichero.